# $route.reload & ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I have a refresh button that calls a scope function `$route.reload` to simulate a refresh on my view. But the problem is when I click it, it is firing off my `ng-animate` on my `ng-view` which makes it look really messy. Is there anyway around this?

**Controller**

```
    $scope.refresh = function () {
          $route.reload();
    };
```

**Index ng-view**

```
 <div ng-view class="slide"></div>
```

I ended up figuring it out, check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

```
$scope.refresh = function () {
    $animate.enabled(false);
    $route.reload();
    $timeout(function () {
        $animate.enabled(true);
    });
};
```